# First, second and third-order bias

Tags: bias, definition

I came across first, second and third-order mean bias of an estimator in a text and I could not find a good reference which explains them properly.
Can somebody please explain these terms to me or post a good reference here?

Comment: These terms may be idiosyncratic to the text.  What is this text and how does it describe or define them?

Comment: It refers to the mean bias of an estimator.

Comment: Then, understanding this is the context, the hits in a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=third-order+mean+bias+of+an+estimator&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) seem to answer your question.

Comment: Funnily enough, that google search gives a few papers on specific third order bias corrections and a link to this question. Definitions are hard to come by apparently...\